# I need to transfers all visits from domain.com/example/xxx to domain.com/mypages/?id=xxx using php

Tags: php

I need to transfers all visits from domain.com/example/xxx to domain.com/mypages/?id=xxx 
using php

Thanks in advance guys, 
How do I do this ?

Comment: Using apache to redirect would be a much lower overhead on the system than attempting to redirect using PHP.  Try mod rewrite.

Comment: Do they want to redirect or simply implement some kind of "seo" type short urls? The question could certainly be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use mod rewrite with an apache `.htaccess` file

[Here is a good help site](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)